# Positioning UIImageViews in UITableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, cgrect

I'm creating a grid of thumbnail images, using a UITableView where each cell display 3. At this stage, I'm simply trying to place 3 static images to get placement/size right. But I'm unable to control the position and size of the thumbnail image. Here's my code for one thumbnail image:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// after getting cell..

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 85.0, 85.0)];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];        
[cell addSubview:imageView];

return cell;

}
```

Is my understanding correct that I control the position and size of the image by setting it in the UIImageView?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scale the image in the view:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 85.0, 85.0)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried adding your line (setContentMode) and it had no effect. Is there anything I should check in the storyboard?

Comment: You are initializing two different imageView, see edit in a minute.

Comment: Holy.. it must be time for a break. Thanks so much, it worked!